# How to replace double quotes with single quotes inside of a string using regex?

Tags: regex, xml, xpath

I have a page which contains `//script[@data-type="application/ld+json"]`

the contents of this script are similar to the following.

```
<script>
{
  "one": "some text here",
  "two": "some "other" text here"
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to replace double quotes with single quotes using regex so I have:

`"two": "some 'other' text here"`

Or just remove the inner quotes completely

I can use the `replace` function

The main problem is I don't know how to match only quotes inside of a string.

Comment: Using a featured engine like Perl it would be hard, let alone using `replace()` function which utilizes a very limited syntax in comparison. So no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it can't be done because your content is ambiguous. Consider:

```
{
  "one": "some text here",
  "two": "some ", "three": " text here"
}
```

You would have to adopt some rule like saying that the `"` after `some` is treated as a terminal quote if followed by `,` or `}` (optionally preceded by whitespace), or as the start quote of a nested string otherwise. That kind of logic seems far beyond what you can express in regular expressions. And in any case, it will sometimes give you the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is like this, maybe you should try something like the below regex.

```
"(?=\w+"| )(?!\w+":)
```

I don't have all of your scope, I just wrote based on your pattern that you put here.

You can test your regex on Sublime or https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to work as expected. It also matches the first(starting) quote even when there're no inner quotes

Comment: It probably would happens if the first part also is somthing like

{
  "one" : "some text here",
  "two" : "some ", "three": " text here"
} with a space before the :